# Apache Felix & OSGi

Tags: apache-felix

I have created an OSGi Bundle using BnDTools OSGi Project and included many external jars under one jar as per my requirements and configured Execution Environment as J2SE 1.8 but on Console getting error as :

Missing Requirements : rt.jar

this jar is available under Build Path of JAVA

Comment: afaik, you should not "require" rt.jar, it's implicitly exported by the osgi container as a jre capability

Comment: Thanks Jeremie... :) Actually the problem was of versioning added to manifest.mf by the BnD Tool.So when i remover the versions and just referred by name,its working.